# Pygame display 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I've created a 2D numpy array, 20x20, that has a random value of either 0, 1, or 2. 
What I want is for each of these values to have a corresponding colour value, and for pygame to display a grid of these corresponding colour values. A 0 becomes a white square, a 1 becomes a red square, and a 2 becomes a green square, for instance. I can't seem to find a way of doing this. My code at the moment is basically a mishmash of tutorials and none of it really works, but here you go:

```
import numpy
import pygame

gridarray = numpy.random.randint(3, size=(20, 20))
print(gridarray)

colour0=(120,250,90)
colour1=(250,90,120)
colour2=(255,255,255)

(width,height)=(300,300)

screen = pygame.pixelcopy.make_surface(gridarray)
pygame.display.flip()
screen.fill(colour2)

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array which contains the colors

```
colors = np.array([[120, 250, 90], [250, 90, 120], [255, 255, 255]])
```

and use your `gridarray` as an index array: `colors[gridarray]`. You'll get an array such as this:

```
array([[[120, 250,  90],
        [250,  90, 120],
        [250,  90, 120],
        ...,
```

Pass it to `pygame.surfarray.make_surface` to turn it into a `pygame.Surface` which you can blit onto the screen.

```
import pygame as pg
import numpy as np


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()

colors = np.array([[120, 250, 90], [250, 90, 120], [255, 255, 255]])
gridarray = np.random.randint(3, size=(20, 20))
surface = pg.surfarray.make_surface(colors[gridarray])
surface = pg.transform.scale(surface, (200, 200))  # Scaled a bit.

running = True
while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    screen.blit(surface, (100, 100))
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```